# Ajax in JSF load all page

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a authentication form , When I click on command button it should refresh the form in case the login is failed , else  redirect the user

I create ajax inside commandButton to check if login is failed , if it is the OutputText will change to : Login failed

I don't what I need to modify to make it work

Here my JSF ,

```
    <h:form id="form_login" >
    <div>
    <!-- email -->
   <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
   <h:inputText id="mail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="#{login.mail}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Entrez votre mail svp" validatorMessage="Email invalide">
<f:ajax event="keyup" render="messageerreur" />
<f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" /> </h:inputText>
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
 </div>
 <h:message id="messageerreur" for="mail" class="recover-password" style="color:#eb6a5a" />
     <!--  Password -->
 <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
 <h:inputSecret id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="#{login.pass}" required="true"  requiredMessage="Entrez votre password svp" > 
</h:inputSecret>
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
 </div>
 <h:message  id="erreurpass" for="password" class="recover-password" style="color:#eb6a5a" />
</div> 
 <br></br>
                                <div class="pull-right">
<h:commandButton id="login_button"  action="#{login.authentification()}" value="Login" class="btn btn-login">
 <f:ajax onevent="click"  execute="form_login" render="login_failed"/> 
  </h:commandButton></div>
<div class="center">                          
<h:outputText id ="login_failed" class="recover-password" value="#{login.failed}" />
 </div>
</h:form>
```

Here the Function in managed Bean :

```
public String authentification()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        System.out.println(getMail());
        System.out.println(getPass());
        if(getMail()!=null && getPass()!=null)
        {
        login_success=marchandBo.authentication(getMail(), getPass());
        }
        if(login_success)
            return "Dashboard_user.xhtml";
        else
            setFailed("Login failed");

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works. Are you sure you have `class="form-control"`, etc? Also try changing from `action` to `f:ajax listener="#{...}"`.

Comment: Oooh , i t works Thank you , Please make it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You define a `class` attribute on JSF components. I've seen this cause all sorts of weirdness. Maybe you wanted `styleClass`?
2. JSF will strip out your HTML5 `placeholder` attribute unless you use a custom renderer (like the omnifaces [Html5RenderKit](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit)). See the link for how you can do this in native JSF-2.2.
3. Your concrete problem is probably caused by the `onevent` attribute. According to the  [f:ajax documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) the attribute name is `event`. You can leave it off to trigger the ajax request on the "default behavior", which in the case of `h:commandButton` is `submit`. With a `event="click"` attribute, you actually *prevent* the default behavior of submitting the form the standard way. This is why adding a `listener` action worked - it duplicated what you had in your `action` attribute.

To sum it up, change your code to the following:

```
<h:commandButton id="loginBtn" action="#{login.authentification}" 
        value="Login" styleClass="btn btn-login">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="login_failed"/> 
</h:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `onevent` of the `f:ajax` tag is intended to be a javascript function that handles the event.  What you want is `event="click"`.  This attribute describes which DOM event will trigger the action.

Comment: I changed , but it doesnt work .. when I click on button it reload the page , Iwant to reload just the form